# How i can download xcode for free?

Tags: ios, xcode, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have OS Ubuntu, but i would like to try developing for IOS

I have installed virtual box, OS X, get apple ID, and then when i go to [main page](https://developer.apple.com/download/) to download `xcode` it offer me to buy it...

But as far as i know it have to be free...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-developer/44390183#44390183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the buy button is just their default button. I don't think it will actually charge you.

An alternative way is to download it through the Mac App Store. This will also have a "buy" button, but I've never actually been charged.

Answer (score 1):

Go to App Store for OS X and search Xcode.
All you need is an Apple ID.

The developer web site require an Apple ID with iOS Development Program purchase.

Comment: Only if they've changed something recently.  You should be able to access *public* downloads (not betas) of Xcode from the developer.apple.com downloads area even with just a free developer membership.  Basically, you create an Apple ID, then you sign in with it at developer.apple.com, and it magically sets a couple of bits to indicate that it is a developer Apple ID.  Or at least that's the way it is supposed to work... unless they've changed things very recently.